# (optional updated in preceding line with no issues) fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I tried searching for this problem on here (and on google), but I wasn't able to find anything helpful (which is why I'm posting).

I'm making a simple incremental game (it's very similar to cookie clicker) for a school project. The premise of the game is that the user clicks a button to get a coin and can then use their coins to buy upgrades (eg. an upgrade that gives them 2 coins per click). I'm getting "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and I can't figure out why. I have two view controllers, my main one and my menu. I'm working on an upgrade that will give the user one free coin per second. The upgrade button is in the menu view controller, but the timer is in the main view controller. Since the timer can't update my bank label (that shows how many coins the user has) while the user is in the other view controller (since the label doesn't exist at that point), I have if/else statements in my selector (the function that the timer runs once per second) that are dependent on a variable called safeCheck that I set as true in the main view controller's viewWillAppear and false in the menu view controller's viewDidLoad. When it's true, one coin is added to the user's bank and this is shown in the bank label. When false, it increments a variable which will be added to the bank when the main view controller's viewWillAppear is called (they don't get added in current code). In viewWillAppear, I am currently doing 2 things: first, I update the bank label and second, I set safeCheck to true. The "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" gets thrown when I exit the menu and load the main view controller. I have checked and the error is not being thrown by updating the bank label. When I comment out the line that sets safeCheck to true, it stops throwing the error. In the debug navigator, the line in my timer selector that updates my bank text is hilighted green, so I think that's what's throwing the error. **I have no idea why it could be throwing the error since my bank label is the only optional it interacts with and viewWillAppear has just updated the bank label with no errors.**

Any help figuring this out will be greatly appreciated. Sorry for the wall of text, I couldn't figure out how to make it shorter and still describe my problem. Below is my code (just the relevant parts out of the main view controller).

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        updateBank(num: MenuViewController.GlobalVariable.tempBank)
        GlobalVariable.safeCheck = true  //when I comment out this line, everything runs with no errors
    }


//click bank label
    @IBOutlet weak var clickBank: UILabel!


//update inBank and bank label
    func updateBank(num: Int){
        GlobalVariable.inBank = num
        bankText()
    }

    func bankText(){
        clickBank.text = "Bank: \(GlobalVariable.inBank)"
    }

//timer
    static func initiateTimer(){
        GlobalVariable.SwiftTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target:self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    static func updateCounter() {
        GlobalVariable.SwiftCounter =  GlobalVariable.SwiftCounter + 1  //increment the counter
        GlobalVariable.inBank = GlobalVariable.inBank + 1
        if (GlobalVariable.safeCheck == true){
            print("Safecheck is true")
            ViewController().bankText()  //I get green error hilight on this line starting with "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=..." 
        }
        else{
            print("Safecheck is false")
            GlobalVariable.safeStore = GlobalVariable.safeStore + 1  //keep track of how many coins need to be added
            print("Safestore = \(GlobalVariable.safeStore)")
        }
    }

struct GlobalVariable{
static var safeCheck = Bool()
static var safeStore = Int()
}
```

Comment: The issue is that your are instantiating a new `ViewController` in this line `ViewController().bankText()`. The `clickBank` property of this new ViewController instance is not yet resolved because the instance is never displayed. Easiest solution would be to convert your timer methods to non static methods by removing the static keyword. And then replace `ViewController().bankText()` with `self.bankText()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't mean to instantiate a new View Controller, thanks for telling me that I did that.  I just want to call bankText.  I need the timer methods to be static so that I can initiate the timer from my structure.  I need to be able to initiate the timer from within my structure so that I can initiate the timer from MenuViewController (my other view controller).  Do you know of any other ways to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the issue by using notifications. First create a notificaiton extension (this can be implemented anywhere in a source file):

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let timerUpdated = Notification.Name("timerUpdated")
}
```

Then in your `ViewController` add and remove notification observer like this:

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(bankText), name: .timerUpdated, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .timerUpdated, object: nil)
    }
```

To post the notification use:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .timerUpdated, object: nil)
```

So basically you can replace `ViewController().bankText()` with `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .timerUpdated, object: nil)` to post the notification which will then trigger your `bankText()` method. Hope this helps :).